# Is there a Qt widget to split a window into a variable number of non-overlapping panes?

Tags: qt

I need to split the main window into an arbitrary, but small, number of widgets, which the user may resize at will, with adjacent widgets automatically decreasing in size to avoid overlap. This may result in 'dead' areas, not covered by any widget.

MDI is too flexible, allowing the user to detach widgets and have them overlap. QSplitter isn't sufficiently flexible. QDockWidget may not be placed (without floating) in the middle of the window.

Is there an appropriate layout widget for the task, without writing some sort of flexible splitter myself?

Comment: Is there a non Qt widget which does the job? Or gets close to what you want?

Comment: @KcFnMi - not that I know of, which doesn't say much.

Comment: Do you mean something like https://github.com/KDAB/KDDockWidgets or so?

Comment: @peppe looks closer. It has features I don't need, like tabs, and I'm not sure it supports everything I want. Will try to built it with CLion and see.

Comment: QDockWidget(s) may be placed (without floating) in the middle of the window!!!

Comment: If you want exactly what you describe, you have to do it yourself I think. I'd probably start with subclassing QFrame and adding mouse event listeners to detect when user grabs the frame and drags it, and then pass the drag action up to parent widget, which would do the resizing of everything. There are some corner cases where you need to think hard how the thing should behave, exactly, and then find a way to implement the behavior (at first thought, it's probably not trivial). Like, user can actually shuffle the widgets around with free resizing, so how do you handle that?